# Javascript(JQuery) transition effect with .removeClass() and .addClass() not working with animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I'm using `fullPage.js` and trying to achieve some effect when jumping sections. Basically I'm trying to have a smooth effect to change the font color of my fixed header menu when jumping from section to section. The desired effect works as follows:

1. As soon as you move from a section(say section  1 for example), the color starts changing(using a linear transition). This is achieved by using `.removeClass()` has been used on the menu.
2. As the next section(call this section 2) is reached, the color change transition has happened when `.addClass()` has been added to my menu.

Now the effect works perfectly why I'm changing from one single color to another. However there is one section where I'm using `Keyframes` on my section to change the color of the menu after some time. I'm guessing this is why the smooth transition color is not working from that section to a section with a single color. Note that this happens only in Chrome but not Firefox.

I'm looking to fix that problem in Chrome. Note that `index == 1` is the section with the changing color menu using keyframes. The other index numbers have color either black or white.

Here's my code:
**JQuery that uses `afterLoad` and `onLeave` of fullPage.js**

```
afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
    if(index == 2){
      reStylize('colourful', 'black', 'white');
    }else if(index == 3){
      reStylize('white', 'colourful', 'black');
    }else if(index == 4){
      reStylize('white', 'colourful', 'black');
    }else if(index == 5){
      reStylize('colourful', 'black', 'white');              
    }
  },
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
  if((index == 1)){ 
    if (direction == 'down' || nextIndex == 5){
      reStylize('black', 'colourful', 'white');
    }else if(nextIndex == 3 || nextIndex == 4){
      reStylize('white', 'colourful', 'black');
    }
  }
}
```

**The reStylize function**

```
function reStylize(colorOne, colorTwo, newColor){
  if($('header').hasClass(colorOne) || $('header').hasClass(colorTwo)
    || $('footer').hasClass(colorOne) || $('footer').hasClass(colorTwo)
    || $('footer a').hasClass(colorOne) || $('footer a').hasClass(colorTwo)){

      $('header').removeClass(colorOne);
      $('header').removeClass(colorTwo);
      $('footer').removeClass(colorOne);
      $('footer').removeClass(colorTwo);
      $('footer a').removeClass(colorOne);
      $('footer a').removeClass(colorTwo);
    }
    $('header').addClass(newColor);
    $('footer').addClass(newColor);
    $('footer a').addClass(newColor);
  }
}
```

**The CSS that is used with the JS**

```
.colourful{
    -moz-animation: color 30s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: color 30s infinite;
    -o-animation: color 30s infinite;
    animation: color 30s infinite;
    -webkit-transition: color 2100ms linear  !important;
    -moz-transition: color 2100ms linear  !important;
    -o-transition: color 2100ms linear  !important;
    -ms-transition: color 2100ms linear  !important;
    transition: color 2100ms linear  !important;    
 }

 @keyframes color {
    0%{color:#978f82 ;}
    9.50%{color:#978f82 ;}
    12.50%{color:#5b6492 ;}
    22%{color:#5b6492 ;}
    25%{color:#c39b79 ;}
    34.50%{color:#c39b79 ;}
    37.50%{color:#fff ;}
    47%{color:#fff ;}
    50%{color:#f0debd ;}
    59.50%{color:#f0debd ;}
    62.50%{color:#70624b ;}
    72%{color:#70624b ;}
    75%{color:#ac2b26 ;}
    84.50%{color:#ac2b26 ;}
    87.50%{color:#938072 ;}
    97%{color:#938072 ;}
    100%{color:#978f82 ;}
}


 .white{
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: color 2100ms linear;
    -moz-transition: color 2100ms linear;
    -o-transition: color 2100ms linear;
    -ms-transition: color 2100ms linear;
    transition: color 2100ms linear;
 }

 .black{
    color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: color 2100ms linear;
    -moz-transition: color 2100ms linear;
    -o-transition: color 2100ms linear;
    -ms-transition: color 2100ms linear;
    transition: color 2100ms linear;
 }
```

You will see that, although I set the transition as `!important` in my animation class, it doesn't work in Chrome. It does work in Firefox though

Comment: possible to put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: I think it's a bit difficult. @TahirAhmed but you can check the site: http://sabirmb.com/Parallax Note that it doesn't work on chrome, so that's what you should use to test :)

Comment: Is it the `Collections` section?

Comment: @TahirAhmed Yep. From home to collections. There is not transition effect on the color change. it just changes instantly

Comment: Right. Apparently, it happens on all the other sections too. So, whenever you are coming form `Home` section to any other section, the transition doesn't happen.

Comment: Exactly @TahirAhmed the problem is with the Home section. For some reason the transition doesn't work on it.

Comment: 2 questions: **1.** why do you not decide to use one of the callbacks between `afterLoad` and `onLeave`? **2.** why does your `reStylize` function need to know the names of 2 colour classes, current and previous?

Comment: @TahirAhmed I'm not really sure what you mean for 1. but for 2. I wrote a quick function to check if I could get what I wanted working. However there is a logic error in that and 3 parameters are not necessary. But for now, I'm only trying to fix the main issue

Comment: very difficult to debug and test on chrome. I want strongly recommend putting together a stripped down version somehow in jsFiddle for people to play around with.

Comment: Will try and do so and update back.